# Is there any evidence that legalizing prostitution decreases violence against women?

Tags: law, prostitution

There are some [debate](http://prostitution.procon.org/view.answers.php?questionID=000122) between pros and cons considering prostitution as a legal job in many countries. One thing that pros say is that it can decrease violence against all women from prostitutes and non prostitutes.

Is there any valid evidence to prove their claims about?

Answer (score 29):

There is definitely evidence that legal prostitution decreases violence against the prostitutes. So even if it has zero effect on women who are not prostitutes, the net effect would be that violence against "all" women would therefore be lower. (And men too since there are male prostitutes as well.) I realize that isn't the angle you were aiming for, but it is mathematically sound.

Here is some of the evidence mentioned in the first sentence: The prostitutes in a legal brothel in Nevada have security, call buttons, they can request that managers keep the intercom throughout the session if they have a new customer or someone they deem suspicious, money is taken out of the room before the session begins, they are tested weekly, and the police are called to arrest abusive "johns": [Info Here](http://esplerp.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Violence-and-Legalized-Brothel-Prostitution-in-Nevada.pdf). Sometimes the prostitutes are allowed to make house calls, but most don't because it's too dangerous. A notable quote is on page 15:

> As one prostitute said, “I don’t go out of this house with anybody I
>   don’t know and I don’t book anybody outside of the house.” To do so is to lose
>   one of the vital protections offered by legalized brothel prostitution: the security of the house and the people in it.

[Here](http://www.11points.com/Dating-Sex/11_Myths_and_Facts_About_Prostitution_in_America) is some evidence that prostitution as a whole is a dangerous profession in the US, where over 99.9% is illegal prostitution. (See Point 2.)

As mentioned in a comment by PoloHoleSet, another obvious benefit of legalized prostitution (or at least decriminalization) is that prostitutes would no longer be afraid (due to fear of legal prosecution) to report crimes against them.

Comment: I am really shocked that none of the answers, including this one, mention a pretty key factor. If a crime is committed against a prostitute, the fact that they do not face a risk of criminal sanctions against them for being a prostitute makes it much more likely that they will be willing to report crimes to the police, give frank and honest accounting of events, and follow through in the process.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Good point, though I think this answer strongly implies that with: "and the police are called to arrest abusive 'johns'". If you feel that it would be better to explicitly state it, feel free to edit, or I will consider editing later when I get more time.

Comment: Ah, I took that more to a factor of legal management and establishments, vs individuals.  I just seemed to feel it would be the main, or a main, factor in this. If I feel strongly about it, I can certainly formulate my own answer, as well.  I certainly did not down-vote on it.

Comment: While I agree with @PoloHoleSet I would like to see some statistics or data that support this idea. The answer does imply this concept, but it isn't directly mentioned and it is a pretty significant difference in threat level to the affected person. I would be very interested in knowing the effects of removing the legal threat has in reporting levels and general safety.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - OK, you convinced me; that would certainly benefit individuals as well. I have updated the answer to incorporate your point. It's so obvious that it should be easy to site evidence of this. I'll look for some.

Comment: @DavidS - absolutely. That's the main reason why I didn't just post an answer of my own with this assumption - I do not have the data at hand to back it up. Looking forward to seeing what "Triple T" finds.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know but apparently -as far as we know it- it helps to prevent. [Studies](https://www.pcar.org/sites/default/files/pages-pdf/the_intersection_between_prostitution_and_sexual_violence.pdf) [emphasize the need](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3987574/) for make a more regulated market because in the end, the prostitution is a sex industry. Researchs made based in the experience of the Netherlands and publsihed in the [American Economy Journal](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/pol.20150299) and the [Research Institute of Industrial Economics](http://www.ifn.se/wfiles/wp/wp996.pdf) (Sweden), regarding the legalization of prostitution gave positive results because:

- Helps the sex workers to organize in groups: Sex workers manage their business by making something like a safe street called Tippelzone, where all workers come together and work in the same zone avoiding dangerous zone.
- Regularization avoid human trafficking: Being recognized as (legal) workers helps to identify and fight human trafficking. It doesn't mean is going to end this, on the contrary, encourage new ways to insert sexual slaves in the street.
- Enable to focus in other areas: Prostitution is not something you talk only because between this industry there are other issues such as violent crimes (not related to sex), drugs, assaults among others. The regularization helped to focus more in this issues.
- Without regulation, human trafficking is on the rise: With political support and fewer unlicensed sex workers, is more likely to reduce human trafficking.

**Does this mean the legalization prevents violence?** Not sure, most times -the study concluded- the relation between crime registered (*something that happened*) and crime perceived (*I think this is unsecure*) does not match statistically. The media has some responsability over there confusing -what [Nassim Talleb called](https://medium.com/incerto/peace-neither-ink-nor-blood-4657956c82ac)- intensity with frequency. The main problem is not the prostitution but crime related drugs issues, which is not a problem in the tippelzone, according to the study. And the swedish research previolusly mentioned finished the study highlightning:

> these predictions have not yet been tested

Comment: I think a fundamental problem with regulated prostitution is the eventuality that the prostitute will be held liable to fulfill her contractual obligation when she has decided that that's not what she really wanted to do.  No quantity of consensual prostitution will ever convert this black menace into a consensual sex act.

Comment: Re: My previous comment: regulations in New Zealand and Germany explicitly grant the right of the prostitute to withdraw consent at any time.  But another menace is lurking under cover of this provision: suppose a client claims that the prostitute withdrew consent and refuses to pay!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not clear that decriminalizing prostitution improves safety and public health, even though researchers have studied its simultaneous 2003 decriminalization in New Zealand and Rhode Island.

It's supposed by some researchers that "indoor prostitution" is safer for the prostitute than street prostitution ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ronald_Weitzer/publication/7701249_Flawed_Theory_and_Method_in_Studies_of_Prostitution/links/555d03f208ae8c0cab2a6b1f/Flawed-Theory-and-Method-in-Studies-of-Prostitution.pdf#page=11)) but other researchers oppose this claim ([link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/35219764/Bad_for_the_Body__Bad_for_the_Heart__Prostitution_Harms_Women_Even_if.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1536778917&Signature=0qSeXaxOuexdlg%2BzRLO6yl5h4B4%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DProstitution_Harms_Women_Even_if_Legaliz.pdf#page=9)).

It is not clear that the increased availability of "indoor prostitution" under decriminalization has any impact on street prostitution at all ([link - see footnote](https://business.baylor.edu/scott_cunningham/w20281.pdf#page=6)).  Unfortunately, the reduction in violence seen among all women in Rhode Island in 2003 was preceded by a rise in violence in 2001-2002, so the decriminalized state was still just as unsafe as its neighbors after the improvement.

Furthermore, it seems likely that decriminalization will enable other crimes against women, such as trafficking into the decriminalized area ([link](https://www.safetylit.org/citations/index.php?fuseaction=citations.viewdetails&citationIds[]=citjournalarticle_505593_38)).

A 2014 study-of-studies determined that at a minimum, we observe that 3 in 10 prostitutes will become victims of violent crime.  Some studies found that 3 in 4 prostitutes were victimized. ([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3987574/))  Nobody imagines that regulations will alleviate this insane risk, but merely that regulation could remove the black market's impenetrable firewall between perpetrators of violence and justice.

Also, decriminalized prostitution contracts will inevitably result in violence if a client changes his mind and refuses to pay, resulting in the poisonous legal quagmire of court proceedings to determine whether *anything happened*.  If the court sides with the dishonest client, then it could become true that the prostitute had been raped.

Comment: Regarding that last paragraph: If read that way, isn't all enforcement of contracts violent? In the end, your money will be forcefully taken from you by the state and/or you'll be put in prison.

Comment: I don't think anybody goes to jail or has any form of physical punishment for failing to fulfill a contract: those kinds of punishments are only available in criminal court.  A prostitution contract thus weasels violence into the civil courts.

Comment: *"the government is called upon to enforce prostitution contracts upon a woman who has changed her mind"* - can you name any real-world prostitution laws where this is actually the case? Those I am aware of explicitly allow the prostitute to revoke the contract at any time.

Comment: @Philipp, thanks for that... you're right: NZ PRA(2003) section 17 makes that explicit, ( http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2003/0028/latest/DLM197867.html ) although it's still true that contested contracts may be referred to the Disputes Tribunal.  What about Germany?  Hmmm...

Comment: The Prostitutionsgesetz (https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitutionsgesetz&prev=search) also has a similar provision.  But it comes with a nasty side-effect: suppose the client refuses to pay!  The establishment that "services were rendered" becomes he-said she-said, and the prostitute is left in the lurch.

Comment: @elliotsvensson If you fail to fulfill a contract and are unwilling/unable to pay fines, you can be imprisoned. However: even if you don't go to prison, somebody entering your home and taking your stuff to reimburse the other side of the contract IS violence. And that's the the police will do if the other party has paid you already.

Comment: @elliotsvensson That's why prostitutes always demand to be paid *before* the act. The problem of finding out what happened behind closed doors in a brothel is always difficult, but criminalizing prostitution makes it even more difficult, because now prostitutes do not have any legal recourse *in theory*.

Comment: @Philipp, but that is contrary to § 1 of the Prostitutionsgesets, in which a right to payment is only ordered ***after*** sexual services are "vorgenommen worden".  That's the logic that provides for the right to withdraw consent... if payment comes first, consent is in trouble!

Comment: @Philipp, it doesn't appear that the NZ law has this requirement about paying after.  But then how is the contract to be enforced, should a prostitute receive payment, withdraw consent, and subsequently not be able to return the money?

Comment: @elliotsvensson This is far more about law than about politics. You might want to ask this question on https://law.stackexchange.com. But the short answer is that the state will not force the prostitute to perform a sexual act she does not want to perform.

Comment: With illegal prostitution - someone gets violent with a prostitute, she does not report it because she was also engaged in illegal activity.  Legalized, she does.  Unless we are assuming that men who get violent with prostitutes ***only*** get violent with prostitutes, I can see a pretty clear causal line between legalizing and a reduction in violence against prostitutes, with a spill-over to the general public, if the perpetrators are more likely to be taken out of general circulation by the criminal justice system.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, this is a sound argument... but it doesn't address the studies that I referenced above that show evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I didn't look at the details of your studies, but it seems like they don't address that aspect, at all. The way you describe most of them is prostitution in some kind of an establishment vs. "street."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, we have no reason to believe that illegal prostitution will cease when legal prostitution is established.  Under this situation with two kinds of prostition: legal and illegal, what's illegal is called "street" and what's legal is called "indoor".  Perhaps this terminology would be different in der Tippelzone but the principle of illegal vs. legal, the danger of illegal, and the endurance of illegal, stands regardless of the ancillary details of "outdoor", "indoor", "street", etc.

Comment: The is a vast, vast chasm between "cease" and "reduce."  You really think that, given the option between legal and regulated prostitution and illegal prostitution on the street, most customers would opt for the latter?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, now you're asking me to speculate.  Instead, let's focus on the studies that I linked above.

Comment: "Unfortunately we do not have data on the street sex market so we cannot test whether decriminalization of indoor sex market affects the street market. *However, empirical evidence suggests the street market has declined substantially since the early 1990s both in Rhode Island and the US while the internet/indoor market has grown (Cunningham and Kendall, 2011)*." I'm not sure how you got the idea that they were somehow claiming the opposite. They were merely stating the difficulty of nailing down number for illegal operations,

Comment: "While other researchers oppose the claim" - the other "researcher" is a policy advocate for an organization with the stated goal "to abolish the institution of prostitution" - you really think that matches up as an honest rebuttal to objective research on the topic? Also, that paper is not research or a study, but a persuasive essay.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, you find somebody with something to write on this issue who doesn't care about the issue enough to do something, and I'll take "unbiased" as a criterion.

Comment: If the "do something" might include legalizing prostitution, and you have a "researcher" who is, as a matter of principle and purpose, opposed to that, regardless of what objective research might find, then they are not a legitimate foil to objective research, and I'm not sure why you think the only possible way to "do something" about the issue is to gun for a total ban.  That would speak to, again, a pretty strong bias on your part, going in.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, I'm not trying to imply what you read there... you're right that "do something about it" easily could mean, "do something to ban it" but all I was trying to specify was "do anything to change current policy" including decriminalize, etc.  My point is that I would be shocked (shocked) to find research by somebody without a motive on this subject.  Therefore we can't use "she has a motive" to dismiss a paper.

Comment: The link you provided was not research.  At all, in any way.  It was an opinion piece.  It was a well-researched and well-informed one, but it was not research, and if you think it was, then I'm not sure you're qualified to assess and cite research.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, that's annoying.  The article by Melissa Farley is published in SAGE Journals, Violence Against Women, and is classified by that journal as a "Research Article".  A quick search for articles by M Farley reveals more than 2,000 citations of her papers.

Comment: Read the article. There's no original research, it's not a longitudinal study, and she gets to cherry-pick which studies she wants to reference to support the opinion she is stating.  There's no original research or analysis of collected research going on.  That's the point of linking/citing, right? To read and assess?  And it doesn't matter if she's published other papers that have been cited.  That's an interesting sleight of hand you did there - respond to an issue with a specific published piece by citing her other works.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, it's not sleight of hand, it's my original wording: "other researchers oppose this claim."

Comment: We're talking about THIS specific article, so making a reference about how often she is cited for her other works, and not this one, as an argument that THIS article is "research," is definitely "sleight of hand."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, this is really pedantic.  I wrote a sentence in my answer saying that some researchers (the persons) oppose this claim.  In order for my sentence to be true, all I need to show is the opposition (check) and the identity of the writer as a researcher (check).  Your objection that I'm not presenting "research" may indeed be fair, but your objection that I'm not being honest is not fair.

Comment: Yes, it certainly is pedantic, but, my original critique was about you basically giving equal weight and false equivalence to objective research and non-research with a pointed, pre-determined agenda going into it. You seem to be arguing my assessment is not accurate, but since have changed the argument to "I used this word when I inaccurately described it." This is particularly relevant since you are dismissing the objectively researched claims and are concluding that the "other researchers" opposition is the more valid point of view.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, one thing I do dismiss is the possibility that claims may be objectively researched when the subject is the legalization of prostitution.  Nobody's hands are clean, and so it's worthless to say that "that is opinion, while this is statistics".

Answer (score -6):

One think to keep in mind is that prostitution can be considered as a degrading act that shames all women.

If a society were to then legalize such a profession, it may disgrace the status of *all* women in that particular society, and as a result, lead to far more violence upon them, due to the fostering of a general stigmatization of women, i.e. inhabitants of that society may perceive women in an inferior light from then on. That would not be an appropiate response of course, but it *would* happen.

Comment: So men wouldn't be stigmatized by male prostitutes?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this actually does or did happen?

Comment: @Dhalsim I have lived in many countries with legal prostitution. The situation you described never seemed to be a problem. Please remember that [answers should be backed up with sources](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3605/18862) so this sort of impasse can be avoided.